# R: Generate coordinate data from user-drawn points?

Tags: r, plot, draw, vector-graphics

I would like to add points manually to a plot (through mouse clicks) and then generate coordinate data from those points.

Is there a package or a set of functions that would let me do this in R?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the base function `locator()` to do this. Try the following, for example:

```
plot(1:4)
df <- data.frame(locator())
## Now, on the plotting device:
## 
##     (1) "Left-click" on each of the four points
##     (2) "Right-click --> Stop" to return to the command-line

## The object that is returned, and assigned to df will look
## something like the following
df
         x        y
1 1.008072 1.032795
2 2.011049 2.002365
3 3.004381 2.995299
4 3.997714 4.011595
```

`locator()` is often useful when you need to precisely place something -- text or a legend, say -- onto a plot in which the coordinate system of the plot isn't easy to read off of the axes.  For instance, try this, clicking once before returning to the command-line:

```
barplot(VADeaths)
text(locator(1), "I clicked here", col="red")
```

Comment: Excellent! Is it possible to have the plot display the points as I click them?

Comment: Sure. You can do `locator(type="p")` to have the points plotted in each of the locations you click. Have a look at its help page, and also that for `locator()`, and then just play around with it for a while to learn about some of the other options/possible applications. Cheers.

Comment: Well just that alone doesn't plot it until all points are entered. I figured it out though. This works: while(nrow(df)<10)df <- rbind(df,data.frame(locator(n=1,type="p")))

Comment: @MikeFurlender -- Interesting. For me, using R on Windows XP, `locator(type="p")` and even `df <- data.frame(locator(type="p"))` do plot the points immediately upon clicking. The behavior must depend on some details of the OS and/or device being clicked upon.